# powershell script to read remote pc monitor info sometimes shows wrong serails

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have been using powershell script in AD environment to get remote pc monitor model/serial to keep inventory, but there are times when script returns nothing or serial number is some number that is nothing like original serial... weird thing is sometimes number returned is identical for different computers... any thoughts on this? There are computers using windows 10 / 11 starting from notebooks with attached external monitors, notebooks with docking stations and several monitors to desktop pc with several monitors.

```
$computername = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter computer name (leave blank for localhost)'

function Decode {
    if ($args[0] -is [System.Array]) {
        [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($args[0])
    }
    else {
        'Not Found'
    }
}

foreach ($Monitor in Get-WmiObject WmiMonitorID -Computername $computername -Namespace root\wmi) { 
    $Manufacturer = Decode $Monitor.ManufacturerName -notmatch 0
    $Name = Decode $Monitor.UserFriendlyName -notmatch 0
    $Serial = Decode $Monitor.SerialNumberID -notmatch 0
    $ManufactureWeek = (Get-WmiObject WmiMonitorID -Namespace root\wmi).WeekofManufacture
    $ManufactureYear = (Get-WmiObject WmiMonitorID -Namespace root\wmi).YearOfManufacture
     
    echo "Manufacturer: $Manufacturer`nName: $Name`nSerial Number: $Serial"
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the raw `SerialNumberID` value for one of the monitors that come out with a garbled name? `Get-WmiObject WmiMonitorID -Namespace root\wmi |Select @{Name='SerialHex';E={[BitConverter]::ToString($_.SerialNumberID)}}`

Comment: Why do you read the `$ManufactureWeek` and `$ManufactureYear` using two more calls to Get-WmiObject on **your local pc** rather than using whatever is already in `$Monitor`

Comment: Set back to $null your variables for each iteration of this loop. This will avoid having the same values... Also keep in mind that WMI queries are subject to failures... So Try Catch may be helpful ;-)